# How to set dates, n number of days apart

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I currently have code that sets all current reminders (4), as the same date. How do I set these 87 days apart.

```
foreach ($request->pets as $pet) {
  $clientPet = $client->pets()->find($pet)->first();
  $clientPet->name = $pet['name'];
  $clientPet->treated_at = $pet['treatedAt'];

  $clientPet->save();

  foreach($clientPet->reminders as $reminders)
  {

    $reminders->scheduled_at   = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $clientPet->treated_at)->addWeeks(12)->subDays(3);
    $reminders->product_id     = $pet['productId'];
    $reminders->application_id = $pet['applicationId'];

    $reminders->save();
  }

}
```

Comment: unable to understand can you describe more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not keeping reference to the last date in your code, but you are always adding just 87 (or as many days) days to the original date so try this

```
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $clientPet->treated_at);
foreach($clientPet->reminders as $reminder)
{

   $reminder->scheduled_at   = $date->addDays(87);
   $reminder->product_id     = $pet['productId'];
   $reminder->application_id = $pet['applicationId'];

   $reminder->save();
}
```

since Carbon is mutable, each `$reminder` will get 87 days more than the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
foreach ($request->pets as $pet) {
   $clientPet = $client->pets()->find($pet)->first();
   $clientPet->name = $pet['name'];
   $clientPet->treated_at = $pet['treatedAt'];

   $clientPet->save();

   foreach($clientPet->reminders as $reminders)
   {

     $reminders->scheduled_at   = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $clientPet->treated_at)->addDays(10);
     $reminders->product_id     = $pet['productId'];
     $reminders->application_id = $pet['applicationId'];

     $reminders->save();
   }

}
```